# If $f$ is a concave function and $f(0) \geq 0$ then $f(a+b) \leq f(a) + f(b)$ for all $a,b >0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Well If I've got a nice understanding, this proof involves the use of *Rolle's and/or Mean Value Theorems*. But I don't even an idea of how to start. We already know that 
$$f\text{ concave}\Rightarrow f''<0$$
but, then...

Comment: A concave function does not need to be differentiable.

Comment: You  only get $f''\le 0$ as a characterization (for twice differentiable functions on an interval).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$  \frac{b}{a+b}f(0) + \frac{a}{a+b}f(a+b) \leq f(a)  $$

since $f(0) \ge 0$ we have

$$   \frac{a}{a+b}f(a+b) \leq f(a)  $$
similarly by interchanging the role $a$ with $b$ we have

$$   \frac{b}{a+b}f(a+b) \leq f(b)  $$

Now by adding last two inequality we arrive to the result.

Answer (score 2):

We may suppose $a \leq b$. First note that $a=\frac a b b+(1-\frac a b) 0$. Hence $f(a) \geq \frac a b f(b)$. Next write b as $\alpha a+(1-\alpha)(a+b)$ and apply the definition of concavity. We get $f(a+b) \leq \frac b {b-a} f(b) - \frac a {b-a} f(a) \leq f(a)+f(b)$ because $\frac a {b-a} f(b) \leq \frac b {b-a} f(a)$