# $f$ Concave function such as $f(0)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f$ a concave function such as $f(0)=0$.

$$f :\mathbb{R^+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

I want to prove that, for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R^+}$: $f(a+b)\leq f(a)+f(b)$

My idea:
Since $f$ is concave then for all $t\in [0,1]$, $f(t.a+(1-t)b \geq tf(a)+(1-t)f(b).$

And by taking $t=1/2$ then we'll have : $f((a+b)/2)\leq 1/2(f(a)+f(b)).$

and if we take $b=0$, then we'll have $f(ta)\geq tf(a)$

But I could not get to resault.

Comment: Use the inequality applied to $2a$ and $2b$ and $t=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $f$ is a concave function and $f(0) \geq 0$ then $f(a+b) \leq f(a) + f(b)$ for all $a,b >0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2555122/if-f-is-a-concave-function-and-f0-geq-0-then-fab-leq-fa-fb-fo)

Comment: Also: [Concave implies subadditive](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/295551/42969).

Comment: But $0$ is not in $\Bbb R^+$. Do you mean $\Bbb R_{\ge 0}$, that is, $[0,\infty)$? (In fact, the proof doesn't use that $a$ or $b$ are not negative.

Comment: YES, I meant $\mathbb{R_{\geq 0}}$