# Convex inequality with the function $f(x)=x\log x$

Tags: functions, inequality, logarithms, convex-optimization

Let $u(t):=t\log t$. This function is convex on $[0,+\infty)$ and $u(0)=0$. How can I prove that$$u(t+h)-u(t)\geq u(h)\quad\forall t,h\in[0,+\infty)?$$
Since $u(0)=0$ using convexity we know that $u(st)\leq s\,u(t)$, where $s\in[0,1]$ but i get confused with the inequalities.

Comment: $-u$ is concave, and therefore subadditive, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2676802/42969.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $f$ is a concave function and $f(0) \geq 0$ then $f(a+b) \leq f(a) + f(b)$ for all $a,b >0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2555122/if-f-is-a-concave-function-and-f0-geq-0-then-fab-leq-fa-fb-fo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, that

$$\begin{array}{rcl} u(t)+u(h)&=&u((t+h)\dfrac{t}{(t+h)})+u((t+h)\dfrac{h}{(t+h)}) \\ &\leq& \dfrac{t}{(t+h)}\cdot  u(t+h)+\dfrac{h}{(t+h)}\cdot  u(t+h)=u(t+h) \quad \forall t,h\in[0,+\infty)  \end{array}$$

Comment: So this would work also for any function which is convex on $(0,+\infty)$ without using the logarithm of this $u$! Interesting

Comment: With the hypothesis of $u(0)=0$ which is also crucial here, but yes.

Comment: @MatteoCalisti Thats true. That's a nice quality

Answer (score 3):

It is one line (\log is monotone):

$$u(t+h)=(t+h)\log(t+h)=t\log(t+h)+h\log(t+h)\ge t\log(t)+h\log(h)=u(t)+u(h).$$

Comment: so actually convexity is not used to prove that!

Comment: No, $x\varphi(x)$ with $\varphi\nearrow$ will work the same. For instance $x\tanh(x)$ is not convex, but the result stands.