# Prove $|f(y) − f(x)| \leq f(|y − x|)$ if $|y − x| ≤ 1/2$ given $f(x)=-x\log_2 x$

Tags: calculus, inequality, logarithms, information-theory

> How do I prove that whenever $|y − x| ≤ 1/2$ it follows that $|f(y) − f(x)| \leq f(|y − x|)$ given $f(x)=-x\log_2 x$?

where $x,y\in[0,1]$

The graph of $f(x)=-x\log_2 x$ function is

[image: -xlogx]

$$
f'(x)=-\log x-\frac{x}{x\ln 2}=-\log x-\frac{1}{\ln 2}=0\implies \log x=-\frac{1}{\ln 2}\\
\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}=-\frac{1}{\ln 2}\implies \ln x=-1\implies x=1/e\approx 0.3679
$$

I was only able to write the following proof:

When $0\le x\le y\le 1$,

\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(y)|&=|-x\log x+y\log y|\\
&=|-x\log x+\frac{x}{\ln 2}+y\log {y}-\frac{y}{\ln 2}+\frac{y}{\ln 2}-\frac{x}{\ln 2}|\\
&\leq |-(x\log x-\frac{x}{\ln 2})+(y\log y-\frac{y}{\ln 2})|+\frac{|y-x|}{\ln 2}\\
&=|\int_x^y \log tdt|+\frac{|y-x|}{\ln 2}=-\int_x^y \log tdt+\frac{|y-x|}{\ln 2}\\
&=-\int_x^{x+(y-x)} \log tdt+\frac{|y-x|}{\ln 2}\\
&\leq -\int_0^{y-x} \log tdt+\frac{|y-x|}{\ln 2}\\
&=-\Big(t\log t-t\Big)_0^{y-x}+\frac{|y-x|}{\ln 2}\\
&=-(y-x)\log(y-x)+(y-x)+\frac{|y-x|}{\ln 2}\\
&=f(|y-x|)+|y-x|+\frac{|y-x|}{\ln 2}
\end{align}

**My Attempt**

Thanks @Balajisb for the hint.

If $f$ is a concave function then $f(a+b)\leq f(a)+f(b)$ for all $a,b>0$
$$
-y\log y=-(y-x+x)\log(y-x+x)\le-(y-x)\log(y-x)-x\log x\\
-y\log y-(-x\log x)\le -(y-x)\log(y-x)\\
f(y)-f(x)\le f(y-x)
$$
$$
D_{\log x}\in(0,\infty]\implies x,y,y-x\geq 0\implies 1\ge y>x>0\\
$$
$$
1>y-x>0\implies -(y-x)\log(y-x)>0
$$
$$
f(y)-f(x)\le f(|y-x|) \;\forall\;(x,y)\;|\;y>x>0\\f(x)-f(y)\le f(|y-x|) \;\forall\;(x,y)\;|\;x>y>0
$$
Therefore,
$$
|f(y)-f(x)|\le f(|y-x|) \;\forall\;(x,y)\;|\;y>x>0\;\&\;f(y)>f(x)\\|f(y)-f(x)|\le f(|y-x|) \;\forall\;(x,y)\;|\;y<x<0\;\&\;f(y)<f(x)
$$

In order to prove $|f(y)-f(x)|\le f(|y-x|) \;\forall\;x,y>0$ we need to also consider the cases $y>x>0\;\&\;f(y)<f(x)$ and $x>y>0\;\&\;f(x)<f(y)$. So I think that's where the condition $y-x\leq 1/2$ lies in.

Case 1 : $y>x>0\;\&\;f(y)<f(x)$
$$
-y\log y<-x\log x\implies y\log y>x\log x\\
x\log x-y\log y<0\\x\log x-\frac{x}{\ln 2}-y\log y+\frac{y}{\ln 2}-\frac{y-x}{\ln 2}<0\\
\int_y^x \log t dt-\frac{y-x}{\ln 2}>0\\
y-x<\ln 2\int_y^x \log t dt=-\ln 2\int_x^y \log t dt=-\ln 2\int_x^y \frac{\ln t}{\ln 2}dt=-\int_x^y \ln t dt\\
<-\int_0^1 \log t dt=-1\times -1=1
$$

> How do I obtain the condition $y-x\leq 1/2$ in this case ?

Comment: The integral for $\log_2$ is not the same as for natural logarithm

Comment: Do you only want this to apply to $x,y$ between $0$ and $1$?  It's certainly not true for arbitrary $x,y$ such that $|x-y| \leq 1/2$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yup. $x,y\in[0,1]$

Comment: @DavidRaveh is it fine now ?

Comment: @DavidRaveh either way I don't think proof I attempted is not gonna reach the required inequality

Comment: @BrianMoehring if $x,y$ are in the range of $0$ to $1$ such that $|x-y|\leq 1/2$, can we have a proof of the required inequality ? would be helpful to get any hint of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume without loss of generality that $ y > x$, and write $z = y - x$, so that $0 \leq  x \leq 1-z \lt 1 \ \text{and} \  z \leq 1/2$ .

Then the concavity of $f$ tells us that the slope of the chord joining $(x,f(x))$ and $(x+z,f(x+z))$ exceeds the slope of the chord joining $(1-z,f(1-z)) $ and $(1,f(1))$, which gives us $f(y) - f(x) \geq -f(1-z)$.

Likewise the slope of the chord joining $(x,f(x))$ and $(x+z,f(x+z))$ is smaller than the slope of the chord joining $(0,f(0)) $ and $(z,f(z))$, which gives $f(y) - f(x) \leq f(z)$.

Hence, $|f(y) - f(x)| \leq \max\{f(z),f(1-z) \} = f(z)$, as $z \leq 1/2$.

Note : If $f$ is convex, and $ a \leq b ;c \leq d $, where $ a \leq c $ and $ b \leq d $, then the slope of the chord joining $(b,f(b)), (d,f(d))$ exceeds that of the chord joining $(a,f(a)), (c,f(c))$.

Comment: It is very nice. (+1) Typos in the chord joining $(0, f(z))$ and $(1, f(1))$? It should be $(0, f(0))$ and $(z, f(z))$. By the way, this is well-known property of convex function.

Comment: @AdityaDhawan  In the first inequality $f(y)-f(x) \geq -f(1-z)$, dont we need $x \leq 1-z \leq x+z \leq 1$ ? So in this case how is $1-z \leq x+z$ ? In the second inequality $f(y)-f(x) \leq f(z)$, we need $0 \leq x \leq z \leq x+z$, how is $x \leq z$  true ? Both of these doesnt seem to fall under $a \leq b \leq c \leq d$ with inequality $\frac{f(d)-f(b)}{d-b} \leq \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$. Can you kind clarify ?

Comment: @Balaji sb Typo in the note fixed. We do not need $ x \leq z $.

Comment: @ River Li Thank you. Typo fixed.

Comment: @AdityaDhawan Dont u need $a \leq b \leq c \leq d$ ?'if this is the case, dont you need $1-z \leq x+z$ for first inequality and $x \leq z$ for second inequality ?

Comment: @AdityaDhawan Thanks

Comment: you mean we take two points $a,d$ in the domain and the points $c,d$ must lie between $a,d$ for the required statement involving slope of the chords to be true, right ?

Comment: What we need is that the left endpoint and the right endpoint of one chord be greater than the the left and right endpoint of the other respectively. So if $[a,c]$ and $[b,d]$ are the chords being considered, we need $ a \leq b$ and $c \leq d$. Apologies for the typo riddled answer, and I hope this clarifies my intentions.

Comment: @AdityaDhawan How do we prove $f(z)\geq f(1-z)$ ? I can see that from the graph though.

Comment: The standard approach would be to look at the derivative, as @AdamZalcman has done.

Comment: I offer a different proof. $x \to \log(x)$ is concave on $(0, \infty)$, and so as $ 0 \lt z \leq 1-z \leq 1$ for $0 \lt z \leq 1/2$, the slope of the chord joining $[z,1]$ exceeds the slope of the chord joining $[1-z,1]$, which gives precisely $f(z) \geq f(1-z)$.

Comment: @AdityaDhawan Nice!

Answer (score 3):

Let wlog $x<y$:

$y \log(y) = (y-x+x) \log(y-x+x) $

By subadditivity: [If $f$ is a concave function and $f(0) \geq 0$ then $f(a+b) \leq f(a) + f(b)$ for all $a,b >0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2555122/if-f-is-a-concave-function-and-f0-geq-0-then-fab-leq-fa-fb-fo)

Hence since $x \log(x)$ is convex:

we have $y \log(y) = (y-x+x) \log(y-x+x) \geq (y-x) \log(y-x)+x\log(x)$.

Hence $y \log(y) - x \log(x) \geq (y-x) \log(y-x)$.
Hence we have proved that $|f(y)-f(x)| \leq f(|y-x|)$, for all $(x,y): x<y, f(y)>f(x)$, since we have proved that $f(y)-f(x) \leq f(y-x)$, for all $y > x > 0$.

$f(x)>f(y)$ and $0<x<y$:

By convexity of $f'(u)$, we have by Jenson inequality,
$$f(x)-f(y) = \int_x^y -f'(u) du \leq -(y-x)f'\left(\frac{y+x}{2}\right)$$
By convexity of $f'(u)$, we have by Jenson inequality,
$$f(y-x) = \int_0^{y-x} f'(u) du \geq (y-x)f'\left(\frac{y-x}{2}\right)$$

We are done if we prove:
$$-f'\left(\frac{y+x}{2}\right) \leq f'\left(\frac{y-x}{2}\right) \iff$$

$$1+\log\left(\frac{y+x}{2}\right) \leq -1-\log\left(\frac{y-x}{2}\right) \iff $$

$$4e^{-2} \geq y^2-x^2 \iff $$

$$4e^{-2} \geq (x+(y-x))^2-x^2 \iff $$

$$\frac{2e^{-2}}{(y-x)}-\frac{(y-x)}{2} \geq x $$

So the proof works either when $f(y)>f(x)$ or when $$\frac{2e^{-2}}{(y-x)}-\frac{(y-x)}{2} \geq x $$.

I think there is a small range missing which is yet to be proved. I hope you can fill that gap. Try and if you cant prove, ping us here in the comments below.

Comment: Here the function is $f(x)=-x\log x$, which is concave, right ?

Comment: yes so $f(x) = x \log(x)$ is convex.

Comment: @Balajisb Did you use the condition $|y - x| \le 1/2$? Without the condition $|y - x| \le 1/2$, the inequality $|f(y) − f(x)| \leq f(|y − x|)$ is not true. For example, $x = \mathrm{e}^{-1}$ and $y = 1$.

Comment: @RiverLi where does the condition $|y-x|\leq1/2$ fits in ?

Comment: The fact that $f(y)-f(x) \leq f(y-x)$ is true for all $y>x>0$.

Comment: @Balajisb If $x, y \in [0, 1]$ and $|y - x| \le 1/2$, then $|f(y) − f(x)| \leq f(|y − x|)$. Without the condition $|y - x| \le 1/2$, it is not true. What's the purpose of your answer? paritial answer?

Comment: @RiverLi, Balajisb How do we incorporate the condition $|y-x|\leq 1/2$ in the proof ?

Comment: This particular problem is taken from a book of information theory, where when we define the entropy $x\log x$ is assumed to be zero. Is that the source of confusion here?

Comment: @Balajisb I found someone downvoted you. It is not me who downvoted you although I commented on your answer. For your edited: Is your proof complete? Did you use the condition $|y - x| \le 1/2$? Or it is implicit in your proof?

Comment: @SoorajS You may analyze $(x,y): x<y, f(y)>f(x)$ to see if it is related to $y - x \le 1/2$?

Comment: @RiverLi the condition $y-x<0.5$ appears in the case $f(x)>f(y)$ and $x<y$. I updated my answer.  There is still a small range missing. I hope Sooraj can fill in the gap. Thanks. Cheers !

Comment: @Balajisb Thanks your the update. The first part is nice. (+1)

Comment: @Balajisb I have updated my post including your suggestion on obtaining the condition $y-x\leq 1/2$, am I thinking it correct? Could you please have a look?

Comment: @SoorajS what you have written seems OK to me. Cheers !

Comment: @Balajisb But think I'm not obtaining the condition $y-x$\leq 1/2 just by taking $y>x>0$ and $f(x)>f(y)$ as I tried in my attempt, it rather gives me $y-x<1$, which is not useful. Is there any way that I can improve my steps to reach the required condition?

Comment: @RiverLi , Balajisb Here log has base 2, therefore I think the last part of your answer should be,
$$
\log(\frac{y^2-x^2}{4})\leq -2\implies \frac{y^2-x^2}{4}\le 2^{-2}=\frac{1}{4}\\
\implies y^2-x^2=(y-x)(y+x)\le1\implies y-x\le\frac{1}{y+x}\\
y+x\le 2\;\&\;\frac{1}{y+x}\ge1/2
$$I don't think its obtaining the required condition $y-x\leq 1/2$

Comment: @SoorajS I am assuming base $e$ in the derivation. This is correct since after proving the inequality $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq f(|x-y|)$, you can multiply by $\log_2(e)$ on both sides of this inequality and change the base to $2$.

Comment: @Balajisb Fine, but its still not providing the condition $y-x\leq1/2$, right ?

Comment: @SoorajS there is a small range in $x,y$ for which i did not prove. I have clearly stated the condition under the which the proof works. But it seems like other guys have proved it nicely. Take a look at their answers. They are nice. Cheers !

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proof.

WLOG, assume that $x \le y$.

We need to prove that
$$|-y\ln y + x\ln x| \le -(y - x)\ln(y - x). \tag{1}$$

Using the identity for $u \ge 0$ (easy to prove)
$$u\ln u =\int_0^1 \frac{u(u - 1)}{1+(u-1)t}\,\mathrm{d} t,$$
(1) is written as
$$\left|\int_0^1 \left(\frac{y(1-y)}{1+(y-1)t} - \frac{x(1-x)}{1+(x-1)t}\right)\,\mathrm{d} t\right|
\le \int_0^1 \frac{(y-x)(1 - (y-x))}{1 + (y-x - 1)t}\,\mathrm{d} t.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\int_0^1 \left|\frac{y(1-y)}{1+(y-1)t} - \frac{x(1-x)}{1+(x-1)t}\right|\,\mathrm{d} t
\le \int_0^1 \frac{(y-x)(1 - (y-x))}{1 + (y-x - 1)t}\,\mathrm{d} t.$$

It suffices to prove that, for all $t \in [0, 1]$ and $0 \le x \le y \le 1$ with $y - x \le 1/2$,
$$\left|\frac{y(1-y)}{1+(y-1)t} - \frac{x(1-x)}{1+(x-1)t}\right|
\le \frac{(y-x)(1 - (y-x))}{1 + (y-x - 1)t}$$
or
$$\left(\frac{y(1-y)}{1+(y-1)t} - \frac{x(1-x)}{1+(x-1)t}\right)^2
\le \left(\frac{(y-x)(1 - (y-x))}{1 + (y-x - 1)t}\right)^2$$
or (clearing the denominators and simplifying)
$$xy[1 - 2(y - x)]t^2 + (2x^2 - xy - 2y^2 + 2y)t(1 - t) + 2(1-y)(1-t)^2 \ge 0 \tag{2}$$
which is true (the proof is given at the end).

We are done.

---

*Proof of (2)*:

It suffices to prove that $2x^2 - xy - 2y^2 + 2y \ge 0$.

If $0 \le x \le 1/3$, then
$$2x^2 - xy - 2y^2 + 2y
\ge 2x^2 - xy - 2y\cdot (x + 1/2) + 2y = 2x^2 + y(1 - 3x) \ge 0.$$

If $1/3 < x < 1/2$, then
$$2x^2 - xy - 2y^2 + 2y
\ge 2x^2 - xy - 2y\cdot (x + 1/2) + 2y = 2x^2 - y(3x - 1) $$
$$\ge 2x^2 - (x + 1/2)(3x - 1) = \frac12(1 + x)(1 - 2x) \ge 0.$$

If $1/2 \le x \le 1$, then $2x^2 - xy - 2y^2 + 2y
= x(2x - y) + 2y(1 - y) \ge 0$.

We are done.

Comment: Nice proof (+1).  It would be nice to get the inequality without too much algebra. Like using Jenson, Subadditivity, log sum inequality etc. I couldnt get it based on what i tried. Let me know if you did get the inequality using simple properties like Jenson, Subadditivity, log sum inequality etc.

Comment: @Balajisb Thanks. A simple proof is expected always.

Comment: @Balajisb: It is Jens**e**n's inequality :)

Comment: Can you identify what is missing in Balajisb's answer? why is it not providing the condition $y-x\leq1/2$?

Comment: @SoorajS Did you see the two new answers. I think we can get it from them.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** I prove $f(y)-f(x)\le f(|y-x|)$ and $f(x)-f(y)\le f(|y-x|)$. The former follows from subadditivity of $f$ which in turn follows from $f(0)=0$ and concavity. The latter follows by analogous arguments applied to $g(x)=f(1-x)$ combined with $g(z)\le f(z)$ which holds when $z\le\frac12$. This explains the significance of the condition $|y-x|\le\frac12$: it unites two upper bounds, one on $f(y)-f(x)$ and one on $f(x)-f(y)$, into an upper bound on the absolute value $|f(y)-f(x)|$.

---

Define $f,g:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$  as
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
-x\log x & x>0 \\
0 & x = 0 
\end{cases}\tag1
$$
and $g(x)=f(1-x)$. This proof is built from the following simple facts which I leave as exercises. The first two concern properties of $f$ of which one can convince themselves also by glancing at the plot in the question. The latter two are generally useful facts about real functions.

**Exercise 1** Both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are concave on their domain $[0,1]$.

**Exercise 2** If $0\le z \le \frac12$, then $g(z)\le f(z)$.

**Exercise 3** If $h:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is concave and $h(0)=0$ then $h$ is subadditive
$$
h(x+y)\le h(x)+h(y)\tag2
$$
whenever function arguments are all in the domain of $h$.

**Exercise 4** If $h:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is subadditive, then
$$
h(y)-h(x)\le h(y-x)\tag3
$$
whenever function arguments are all in the domain of $h$.

**Proof** Assume without loss of generality that $x\le y$. There are two cases: either $f(x)\le f(y)$ or $f(x)>f(y)$. If $f(x)\le f(y)$ then exercises $1$, $3$ and $4$ immediately give us
$$
f(y)-f(x)\le f(y-x)=f(|y-x|).\tag4
$$
Suppose then that $f(x)>f(y)$ and set $a:=1-x$ and $b:=1-y$. We have $b\le a$ and $g(b)<g(a)$, so exercises $1$, $3$ and $4$ give us
$$
g(a)-g(b)\le g(a-b).\tag5
$$
However, $g(a)-g(b)=f(x)-f(y)$. Moreover, $a-b=|y-x|\le\frac12$ so by exercise $2$ we have $g(a-b)\le f(|y-x|)$. Thus,
$$
f(x)-f(y)=g(a)-g(b)\le g(a-b)\le f(|y-x|)\tag6
$$
which combined with $(4)$ completes the proof.$\square$

Comment: It is very nice. (+1) By the way, Balaji sb also used the  subadditive property.

Comment: Nice +1. I had the same proof in mind except that i could not prove $f(1-x) \leq f(x)$ for $0<x<1/2$. Any simple proof you have in mind for this ?

Comment: @Balajisb Well, the simplest is probably to look at the plot, but if you prefer something more rigorous, here's one idea: Let $\Delta(x)=f(x)-f(1-x)$ and note that $\Delta'(x)=-2-\log(x(1-x))$. For $x\in[0,1]$ we find three zeros $\Delta(0)=\Delta(\frac12)=\Delta(1)=0$ and two extrema (since $\Delta'(x)=0$ leads to a quadratic equation with two roots). Also, for $x$ slightly less than one half we have $\Delta(x)>0$ since $\Delta(x)=\int_x^{1-x} (1+\ln t) dt$ and the integrand is positive because $1/e < 1/2$. Thus, $\Delta(x)$ is non-negative for $x\in[0,\frac12]$ and the conclusion follows.

Comment: @AdamZalcman Thanks !

Comment: @AdamZalcman I can see that the integrand is positive when $x$ is slightly less than $1/2$. But looking at the graph of $f(x)=-x\log x$ the integrand must be positive whenever $x\leq 1/2$, except may be close to zero. How can we prove that?

Comment: @SoorajS This follows from four facts: 1. $\Delta$ is differentiable and hence continuous on $[0,\frac12]$. 2. $\Delta$ crosses the $x$ axis at $x=0$ and $x=\frac12$. 2. Its derivative changes sign exactly once in $[0,\frac12]$ because $\Delta'(x)=0$ leads to quadratic equation with two roots one of which, say $x_1$, is in $[0,\frac12]$. 3. For $x$ near the right end of $[0,\frac12]$ we have $\Delta(x)>0$. All this implies that $\Delta$ increases after crossing the $x$ axis at $x=0$ until maximum at $x_1$ and then decreases until it hits the $x$ axis again at $x=\frac12$. See my last comment.

Answer (score -1):

We have a simple proof for $a,x\in(0,1)$ such that $|a-x|\leq 1/2$

We have for $a>0.5$:

$$g\left(x\right)=-\left|a-x\right|\ln\left(\left|a-x\right|\right),f\left(x\right)=\left|a\ln a-x\ln x\right|,g''(a/2)-f''(a/2)=0,g(a)=f(a)$$

It's not hard to see that :

$$x\in[a/2,1),g''(x)-f''(x)<0;x\in(0,a/2),g''(x)-f''(x)>0$$

For $a,x\in(0,0.5]$ we have :

$$x\in(0,|a-x|),g''(x)-f''(x)<0;x\in(|a-x|,a),g''(x)-f(x)<0;g'''(a/2)-f'''(a/2)=0;g'''\left(\left(\frac{1}{a}-1\right)a^{2}\right)-f'''\left(a^{2}\right)=0$$

And so on.

I think you can finish by yourself :-)